# you do not have permission to access this location KCFinder

Tags: laravel

I have problem with accessing the upload folder in kcfinder. For security purpose disable is set to true in config.php as

```
'disale'=>true
```

How can the upload folder is accessible for logged in user in laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for suggestion, [Laravel-CKEditor-Bundle](https://github.com/AdrianSkierniewski/laravel-ckeditor) provide this feature by default for logged in user access with .

KCFinder use php `$_SESSION`, when you create `$ckeditor = new CKEditor();` (second parameter can disable KCFinder) `$_SESSION['KCFINDER'] = array('disabled' => false);` is set and KCFinder start to works.

Now user can upload files on server! After user logout() you must use `session_destroy()` to disable KCFinder

Hope this information will help you!